# wp_mail doesnt work inside transition_comment_status

Tags: comments, wp-mail

I need to send a notification for a visitor whose comment has been published.
I created this function to do it:

```
/*************************************************
** COMMENT APPROVED HOOK
*************************************************/
add_action('transition_comment_status', 'siteit_comment_approved', 10, 3);
function siteit_comment_approved($new_status, $old_status, $comment) {

    if($old_status != $new_status) {
        if($new_status == 'approved') {

            if(is_email($comment->comment_author_email)) {

                $data['pid']    = $comment->comment_post_ID;
                $data['ptitle'] = get_the_title( $data['pid'] );
                $data['plink']  = get_permalink( $data['pid'] );
                $data['name']   = $comment->comment_author;
                $data['email']  = $comment->comment_author_email;
                $data['date']   = $comment->comment_date;

                $subject    = of_get_option(THEME_PREF.'ntf_cmnt_approved_esubject');
                $message    = of_get_option(THEME_PREF.'ntf_cmnt_approved_ebody');

                if( $subject && $message ) {

                    $subject = str_replace('[author_name]', $data['name'], $subject);
                    $subject = str_replace('[post_title]', $data['ptitle'], $subject);

                    $message = str_replace('[author_name]', $data['name'], $message);
                    $message = str_replace('[author_email]', $data['email'], $message);
                    $message = str_replace('[comment_date]', $data['date'], $message);
                    $message = str_replace('[post_title]', $data['ptitle'], $message);
                    $message = str_replace('[post_link]', $data['plink'], $message);

                    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    $headers[] = 'From: '.of_get_option(THEME_PREF.'define_sitename_meta').' <'.of_get_option(THEME_PREF.'define_admin_email').'>';



                    $mailResponse = wp_mail( $data['email'], $subject, $message, $headers );

                    // if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    //     echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">Mail DATA:'."<br>";
                    //     print_r($data);
                    //     echo '</pre>'."<br>";

                    //     echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">subject:'."<br>";
                    //     print_r($subject);
                    //     echo '</pre>'."<br>";

                    //     echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">message:'."<br>";
                    //     print_r($message);
                    //     echo '</pre>'."<br>";

                    //     echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">message:'."<br>";
                    //     print_r($headers);
                    //     echo '</pre>'."<br>";

                    //     echo '<pre style="z-index: 999; position: relative;">MailResponse:'."<br>";
                    //     print_r($mailResponse);
                    //     echo '</pre>'."<br>";
                    // }
                }

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Down the code I added some prints to check if the data is correct.
All the `print_r`'s returns the correct data. Just the "`$mailResponse`"
returns nothing.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***
I have placed this function before the prev code

```
// define the wp_mail_failed callback 
function action_wp_mail_failed($wp_error) {
    return error_log(print_r($wp_error, true));
}

// add the action 
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);
```

Which helped me track the problem (using headers wrong).
I share this in the hopes this helpes anyone while debugging `wp_mail()`